# How did Alistair's wish come true at the end?

Tags: dc, dc-extended-universe, wonder-woman-1984

In *Wonder Woman 1984*, Max Lord gained the powers of the Dreamstone (by wishing to become it), and was granting the wishes of people around the world, using a Global Broadcast Satellite signal.

While Max was doing this, his son, Alistair, made the following wish:

> Alistair: I wish you were here, Daddy. I wish you'd come back. Daddy, please!

Since Max later renounced his wish to become the Dreamstone, and everything in the world went back to normal, how did Alistair's wish still come true at the end?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Max reuniting with Alistair at the end had nothing to do with Alistair's wish for him to come back.

Alistair had already wished for his father's greatness in an earlier scene.

> MAX: Alistair! I've missed you, buddy. Come. Sit down with Daddy. I'm sorry. But, your dad is on the absolute precipice of everything. Remember when I told you that I would be number one? Do you remember? Your dad? Well, I'm inches away. Huh? I know it's hard. I know. But listen, I also know what you wish for, and I wish for it, too. Do you hear that? I wish for it, too.
>
> ALISTAIR: I just wish I could be with you...
>
> MAX: No! You don't use your one wish like that, Alistair. You don't wish for something that you already have. You wish for greatness, for success. That's why I’m doing all of this. Don't you see that my greatness is your greatness? Huh?
>
> ALISTAIR: **Then I wish for your greatness.**
>
> MAX: No. No! Thank you. I love you so much. And I promise you, one day, everything is going to make sense. And one day, you'll thank me. But right now, I, uh... Right now, I need you to stay here with Emerson, okay? I'll be back. You stay here.
>
> <sub>*Wonder Woman 1984*</sub>

There was a gust of wind after Alistair made that wish, indicating that it was granted. And since the Dreamstone only grants one wish per person, it follows that Alistair wouldn't have been granted any more wishes after that. At least, not by the Dreamstone. So when Alistair later wished for his father to come back, that second wish had no effect. Note that there was no gust of wind in that instance.

Why then did Max come for Alistair, if that wish had no effect? The answer is simple. During his final showdown with Diana, Max realised Alistair was alone and in danger.

> ALISTAIR: Daddy! Daddy!
>
> MAX: Alistair! Alistair! My son! Alistair!
>
> ALISTAIR: Daddy! Daddy! Help me, Daddy! Daddy! Daddy!
>
> MAX: **Wait. My son! I can see my son!**
>
> DIANA: Save him, Max.
>
> MAX: **I have to save my son.**
>
> ALISTAIR: Daddy!
>
> MAX: Alistair.
>
> ALISTAIR: Daddy! Daddy!
>
> MAX: My... Alistair. I renounce my wish!
>
> <sub>*Wonder Woman 1984*</sub>

Quite *how* Max realised Alistair was in danger wasn't clearly explained, but it likely had something to do with Diana's lasso, which was wrapped around his ankle at the time.

In an earlier scene, Diana told Steve Trevor that the lasso could make people *see* the truth, as well as tell it, and she used it to show him how [Asteria](https://dcextendeduniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Asteria) singlehandedly held back an army of men, so that the other Amazons could flee to Themyscira.

However it happened, Max clearly knew Alistair needed him, and dropped everything he was doing to go to him. Not because Alistair wished for that to happen, but simply because Max genuinely loved his son, and couldn't bear the thought of losing him.

> MAX: Alistair! Alistair! Alistair!
>
> ALISTAIR: Daddy! Daddy!
>
> MAX: Alistair! Alistair. Oh, Alistair, Alistair. I'm so sorry, baby.
>
> ALISTAIR: **I'm so glad I wished you’d come. I knew it would work.**
>
> MAX: **No. That is not why I'm back.** No. I've been lying to you. I'm not a great guy. In fact, I'm a pretty messed up, loser guy. And I made terrible mistakes. But you… **you don't ever have to make a wish for me to love you. I'm here because I love you.** I just… I just wish and I pray that, one day, I'll be able to make you proud enough that you'll be able to forgive me. And love me. Because I'm nothing to be proud of, Alistair.
>
> ALISTAIR: I don't need you to make me proud. I already love you, Daddy. You're my dad.
>
> <sub>*Wonder Woman 1984*</sub>